# R extracting job titles from list of sentences

Tags: r, list, nlp, feature-extraction, sentence-similarity

I am currently writing a script (In R) to extract job titles from sentences which are from biographies of various corporate executives. I have a list of job titles and a list of sentences from the biography and I was wondering how I would go about extracting a list of the job titles in each sentence. I've tried breaking the sentences down into words (same with the job titles) and matching them using %in% and it works but it doesn't pull out whole phrases (Board of Directors is just "Board" and "Directors" I can't include "of" as a bunch of unwanted of's will be pulled out"

```
job_title <- list("board of directors", "VP of sales")
sentences <- list("He was a member of the board of directors", "He joined as 
VP of sales", "He was born in 1968")
```

So essentially I would like some code to look through each of the sentences, match it to the job_title and pull out the job title so that the result is:
a list of "board of directors" & "VP of sales.
Many thanks!

Comment: Try package `stringr`. `stringr::str_extract(unlist(sentences), unlist(job_title))
`.

Comment: That's what I'm using currently for the individual words!
Can that extract whole phrases from the sentences?

Comment: @Dyem I suggest you to include a portion of the code that you tried as well as the libraries that you are using to find an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, I tried your suggestion and I get a warning: "Warning message:
In stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Comment: It also only seems to extract some of the job titles (one or two) from the sentences for some reason when I use it on my larger data set.

Comment: You are right, it does issue a warning. But given your example data the output is `[1] "board of directors" "VP of sales"        NA` which seems to be right.

Comment: Yeah, I see why now, it compares the first element of each list, then the second etc. I've fixed it now by looping through each element 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  if(i == 1) {
    # check for board of directors
    dir_list <- as.integer(grepl(job_title[1], sentences, fixed=TRUE))
  } else {
    # check for vp sales
    cp_list <- as.integer(grepl(job_title[2], sentences, fixed=TRUE))
  }
}
```

This gives:

```
dir_list as 1, 0, 0 and cp_list as 0, 1, 0
```

Where 1 denotes that the string you were looking for was found in the relevant sentence. For example, board of directors was found in sentence 1 and vp sales was found in sentence 2. So, in case you have both in a sentence, both the lists would have 1, and in case nothing is found, you will have 0. You can now choose what you want to do with these values based on your requirements.

Comment: Hmm, that's very close and perhaps I can make do. Ideally I'd rather the output be a list of all the job titles that came up

Comment: I could not understand your second sentence but glad to know it is close enough to what you require, if true.

Comment: The output would ideally be a list type object containing ("board of directors" ,"VP of sales")

Comment: Could you post your sample output as a table/data frame, I am not quite able to comprehend you